# Connecting PHP Web Service and ASP.NET website to same MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, asp.net, apache, iis

I created a website using ASP.net and it's accessing MySQL through visual studio using IIS and there are some web services developed in PHP [tested using Apache Server] for the android application. Now, I am able to run both Asp.net website and android application using the same host by running both the servers on the same machine.

But how can I use the same MySQL database for both the purposes. How can I redirect the requests for both asp.net web services and php requests to the same database?

Comment: I can't see the difficulty. ASP.NET and PHP can connect to same database at the same time. Why not?

Comment: What are your worries, it's the same as if you are connecting them to different databases. Your question seems to me like "How can I open google.com both on Chrome and Firefox". You just do it, there's no special work.

Comment: I believe that on my system there are two MySQL, one of them is bundled with visual studio and another one bundled with XAMPP Server..

Comment: The ASP.NET website is using the database bundled with it and php web services are using the MySQL bundled with Apache server. Now, I want to use just one of them for all database queries. How can I do that ?

Comment: lol, no mater how many mysql servers and databases you have ran, on one host, one port you can have only one server, and on this server you can have only one database with a name. So, `my.server.com:3306` with daatabse `test` is only one. Just point your ASP.NET to `my.server.com:3306` db `test` and your PHP as well

Comment: AS I am using two different servers, So I changed the default port of apache to 81. Now for ASP.Net I am using my.server.com [default port] and for php I am using my.server.com:81  . Now how can I direct them to same database. I'm not getting it.. Please help. It's very important

Comment: What you did NOT understand. No matter which port the web server is using, you can tell your script to use DATABASE which is NOT on the PORT OF THE WEBSERVER. For instance, if I run localhost on apache wit port 120 and you run mysql (even without webserver), on your host on port 3000, I can say to my script `mysqli_connect("your.server.com:3000", "user", "pass");`. If you have localhost MYSQL on 3306 just tell both scripts (THAT IS NOT BOUND TO WEBSERVER) to connect to localhost:3306

Answer (score 0):

It depends, but generally, connection strings in Asp.Net are stored in a file called web.config, in the root folder of the application.
I don't know if php have a central place to store connection strings, but in both cases you need to change that.

Comment: I believe that on my system there are two MySQL, one of them is bundled with visual studio and another one bundled with XAMPP Server..    The ASP.NET website is using the database bundled with it and php web services are using the MySQL bundled with Apache server. Now, I want to use just one of them for all database queries. How can I do that ? –  user3667929 2 mins ago    edit

Comment: I never heard about "MySql bundled with VS".. Are you sure it's not SQL Server? Anyway, you need to find the connection strings and modify them to suit your needs.